# Adding hyperlinks in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on storing the body of emails in sql server as ntext. The email body which I'm storing  has hyperlinks like "view my website". I want to represent this normal text as hypelink?
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the text as a normal insert.  You may want to consider using something like FCKEditor to allow your users to format the email properly unless your going to be able to control how the HTML is created.  You will want to make sure your columns `datatype` and size are appropriate.

Not knowing your table schema here is a very basic example.

```
Insert into Emailtable
  ('emailHtml', 'emailText')
Values
  ('<HTML><Head></Head><Body><a href="http://www.mysite.com">view my website</a></Body></HTML>', 'Text version of the email')
```

If your going to have spaces and special characters in your link you could HTML encode the link so when it stores it and retrieves it you know your getting the right values.

Comment: thank for giving me good points. I want my user to edit the body of the email also . So How can I use the editor tool. I haven't got any knowledge about editors. Can you please tell me what are these? how can I use them? and what are the types in this tools.

Comment: sure here is the link to their docs: http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide we use it and it's pretty awesome.

Comment: :In above code INSERT INTO EMAILTABLE ('emailHTML','EMAILTEXT') what is emailhtml field. Can you show me how to create it . what should I declare in EmialHTML field while creating

Comment: emailHtml is the html file your looking to insert. If your using FCKeditor you would just insert the output from there. If your creating the data yourself you would insert whatever HTML you created.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the text as formatted HTML and when you sent it with your email client (not sure how you will be sending these) set the client to send the message as HTML formatted.  Then it's just a matter of adding the  tags to the NText.

Comment: I'm just inserting into  table manually like emialBody='this is the email receive and bla blaa........ now here "view my website " is the hyperlink'. can you  please advise how to do formatted HTML insertion in sql.

Comment: Yeah! now I got your point after viewing Robert message. But i need some information on editor tools

Answer (score 0):

the sql type named text is appropriated for html content(including hyperlinks).
In your page you shoud use HtmlString class to show htm content.

Comment: yes, in dotnet use HtmlString class constructor.
In php, use echo or printf